# How to exit a function if observable result is equals to certain value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this piece of code in my angular 6 application:

```
publish() {
    change.subscribe((result: boolean) => {
        if(!result) return;  // exit publish function
    });
    // continue
}
```

I want this publish function to continue executing only if result is true.

How to manage this ?

Comment: continue inside subscription or outside ?

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan outside the subscription. I mean continue the publish function

Comment: @justDan a button from view: `<button (click)="publish()"></button>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is impossible, you should put your `publish` function code inside your subscription, or there is another way you can do, you can use `.toPromise()` and `async/await`, if you will get your data one time and not in a stream

```
async publish() {
    const result = await change.toPromise();
    if(result) {
     // your publish function code here
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Converting observable to promise is always a **bad idea**, so better is just to create local variable and assign a value from `yourObservable` to this local variable.

```
async publish() {
    let doBreak = false;

    yourObservable.subscribe((result) => {
        if (!result) {
            doBreak = true;
        }
    }

    if (doBreak) {
        return;
    }
}
```